# python3.x: index out of range

Tags: python

```
for i in range(len(text_list)):
    for j in range(len(text_list[i])):
        if text_list[i][j] in ban:
            text_list[i]=text_list[i][:j]
```

there occurs an error in the third line.
I don't know what to do.
I think there should not be any error..

Comment: what are the your variables? what exactly is `text_list`? what is `ban`?

Comment: ban=[' ', '\t', '\n', '.', ',', ';', ':', '–', '—', '-', '[', ']', '{', '}', '(', ')', '’', '"',
        "'", '!', '?', '/', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&',]

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if there is a character in the text_list[i](it is string) that is in the list 'ban', i should make it with out that character and following alphabets

Comment: is text_list equal in both dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

This line changes the length of `text_list[i]`:

```
text_list[i]=text_list[i][:j]
```

So the next iteration of `for j ...` is invalid.  Perhaps after modifying `text_list`, you should `break` out to the next higher `for i ...` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the list during iteration. If your if condition suceeds, you will cut the rest of that row. So in the next iteration you run to a, out of bounds error. This is basically the same as writing:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(arr)):
  print(arr[i])
  arr = arr[:i] # could be simply arr = []
```

Answer (score 0):

never mutate your list during iteration, as your index will be shifting.  Instead create a new list, maybe have a look at list comprehension: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html